# How should I interpret 一个颗状星的行星?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> 这个概念在汪淼的头脑中萦绕。为什么那个世界的太阳运行会没有规律？**一个颗状星的行星**，不管其运行轨道是正圆还是偏长的椭圆，其围绕恒星的运动一定是周期性的，全无规律的运行是不可能的……汪淼突然对自己很恼火，他使劲地摇头想赶走头脑中的这一切，不过是个游戏嘛，但他失败了。
> <sub>刘慈欣,《三体》 (see e.g. [this](https://www.sohu.com/a/201784612_99927670))</sub>

I'm not sure how to interpret 一个颗状星的行星 in the above.  Google Translate gives me "a star-shaped planet".  Although the context is suggesting a meaning more along the lines of "a satellite-state planet."  Or maybe it's just a typo.

**Question**: How should I interpret 一个颗状星的行星?

Comment: Some versions of the book get this correct, that is "一个恒星的卫星"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the answer given on 知乎.com, "一个颗状星的行星，不管其运行轨道...." is a typeset mistake. The correct sentence is "一个恒星的行星，不管其运行轨道……".

Note, 行星 (planet, such as earth, moon) is a star circling the 恒星 (fixed star - sun, for instance) in a regular path and speed.

Answer (score 2):

> 一个[**颗状星**]的行星，不管其运行轨道是正圆还是偏长的椭圆，其围绕[**恒星**]的运动一定是周期性的，全无规律的运行是不可能的

- 一个[**颗状星**]的行星 = a [**granular star**]'s planet
- 其围绕[**恒星**]的运动一定是周期性的 = which motion around the [**star**] must be periodic

其(which) refers to 行星 (planet)

颗状星 and 恒星 are the same things in these sentences.

Most likely,  颗状星 is a typo, replace it with 恒星 would solve the mystery

> 一个[**恒星**]的行星，不管其运行轨道是正圆还是偏长的椭圆，其围绕[**恒星**]的运动一定是周期性的，全无规律的运行是不可能的

Actually, it is simpler to write:

**一颗行星**，不管其运行轨道是正圆还是偏长的椭圆，其围绕恒星的运动一定是周期性的，全无规律的运行是不可能的

The term 行星 (planet) already indicated it belongs to a 恒星 (star), no need to mention "a star's" in "a planet"

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a typo.

**颗** in Chinese has a meaning of *small and round stuff*, such as a small and round particle, so **颗状星** means *a star like a small and round particle*.

According to the context, it says *the planet's motion around the sun must be periodic*, so **颗状星的行星** just means a planet, and **颗状星** just emphasizes the condition of planet's periodic motion, that is, if the planet is small enough compared to the sun, the planet's motion must be periodic.

Answer (score 0):

颗状星 is definitely a typing mistake, I have read threebodyproblems many times, and I'm sure that there's no such thing.
And in my whole life, I have never heard anyone using that weird word.